# Image is not showing in WIX blog list page while creating a post by rest api

Tags: rest, post, blogs, velo

I am using Laravel to send a post request to create a post on WIX blog by rest API. All is working well, only the issue I have faced image in blog list is not showing but in single blog page it's showing perfect. If anyone know the solution please help me, here is my draft post object:

```
$post_field = [
            "draftPost" => [
                "title" => $topic->topic,
                "memberId" => $memberId,
                "heroImage" => [
                    "id" => "b5067f_24e7cb534efa4ca2843a24a29f7a8d8a~mv2.jpeg",
                    "url" => "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b5067f_24e7cb534efa4ca2843a24a29f7a8d8a~mv2.jpeg",
                    "altText" => $topic->topic,
                ],
                "richContent" => [
                    "nodes" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "IMAGE",
                            "id" => "",
                            "imageData" => [
                                "containerData" => [
                                    "width" => [
                                        "custom" => "700px",
                                    ],
                                    "alignment" => "CENTER",
                                    "spoiler" => [
                                        "enabled" => false,
                                    ],
                                    "height" => [
                                        "custom" => "800px",
                                    ],
                                    "textWrap" => true,
                                ],
                                "image" => [
                                    "src" => [
                                        "private" => false,
                                        "url" => "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b5067f_24e7cb534efa4ca2843a24a29f7a8d8a~mv2.jpeg",
                                        "id" => "b5067f_24e7cb534efa4ca2843a24a29f7a8d8a~mv2.jpeg",
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "type" => "HTML",
                            "id" => "",
                            "htmlData" => [
                                "containerData" => [
                                    "width" => [
                                        "custom" => "750px",
                                        "spoiler" => [
                                            "enabled" => true
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    "height" => [
                                        "custom" => "12000px"
                                    ],
                                    "alignment" => "CENTER"
                                ],
                                "source" => "HTML",
                                "html" => "{$topic->fullBlog->content}"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "media" => [
                    "displayed" => true,
                    "wixMedia" => [
                        "image" => [
                            "id" => "b5067f_24e7cb534efa4ca2843a24a29f7a8d8a~mv2.jpeg",
                            "altText" => $topic->topic,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "publish" => true,
            "fieldsets" => ["URL"]
        ];
```

The `$topic->fullBlog->content` variable contains various HTML elements like h2, p, a tag, and all is working well, only my issue with image in blog list page.